# Magento 2: My Headless Magento catalog with guest cart to redirect to magento vanila checkout page but need to know how to transfer session

Tags: magento, magento2, cart, magento2.1

Hi I have created a reactjs single page catalog using Rest API and we still have live magento 2.1 website running in vanilla mode.

Our live vanilla website support all required payment modes and therefore want my react web app to redirect checkout on live magento website.

I have successfully build the react app which can add products in cart and view cart using quoteID and Quote Mask ID. Now I need to know like vanila Magento can I set some session or cookies and then redirect user to live Magento website checkout page.

Now I have failed to understand how magento vanila frontend identifies guest user pulls exact cart items on their default cart page. what exactly are they storing in cookie or localstorage of the browser that they are able to map to the quote id in the backend.

If someone can direct me will be great. I have already looked into Quote table, Quote_items table and vistor table too but did not find any link to PHPSESSIONID. Now I doubt whether they even rely on it.

**[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** is my live website
and **webapp.example.com** is my PWA/ReactJS based which consumes Magento's Web api.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh, do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct
(
   \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager $sessionManager
)

{
    $this->_session = $sessionManager;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $sessionID = $this->_session->getSessionId();
}
```

URL: https://www.example.com?SID=sessionid

Example: https://www.example.com?SID=v32hjtpgt8e12jorc0tksekkj6

Magento store sessionid at cookie and session data at server which location is define in env.php

Comment: Well how does it guarantee product added anonymously in guest cart via REST api will be auto transferred??

Comment: thank you for the answer however I would like to know. Will my quotes/items be added against this sessionId even if I am using magento's REST API.

Comment: No, that will not help for REST API